# django and comet

Tags: django, comet

What should i use to implement comet on django?

All things i've found on google seems outdated. Some people point to `orbited.org` or `hookbox.org`, but both of them are just dead now. How people solve this problem nowadays?

Comment: Orbited is very much not dead, they've just been having problems with the website lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) which is a third party service that will allow you to push events to your browser with a drop-dead simple API. They have a free sandbox plan that comes with 100k messages per day and 20 connections.

Alternatively, you could run [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) on your server to push events down.

Django isn't really designed for long polling and comet.